# What does this code mean with stripping leading zeroes?

Tags: python

```
eval("".join(token.lstrip('0') for token in s.split()))
```

Where `s` is something like `'02 + 00030 - 76'`.

All I know is that it strips the zeroes in front of the `02` and `00030` so that it can evaluate it as `2+30-76`. However, I don't understand how exactly it does this. Could someone explain this combination of functions to me?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Lets break it down by starting with the expressions inside.

```
token.lstrip('0') for token in s.split()
```

In Python, this is a generator expression. Rather than evaluating the statement and creating a list from the expression and storing in memory, the generator expression will create each element, one at a time so you can actually use it for very large (and even infinite!) sequences without sacrificing performance.

s.split() returns a list by splitting a string by its whitespace. Therefore, this line means, "for each token in the string, strip out all the 0's at the beginning of the string.

```
"".join(//result of inner expression)
```

This is a performant way in Python of creating a string by using a list. This basically concatenates each element in the list with an empty string.

```
eval
```

This evaluates the argument as a Python expression.

Comment: Technically, it's a generator expression, not a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

```
for token in s.split()
```

`s.split()` evaluates to `['02', '+', '00030', '-', '76']`

Then you do `token.strip('0')` which converts the list to - `['2', '+', '30', '-', '76']` by removing leading 0s from each token.

Finally `"".join([..])` joins them back into `'2+30-76'`.

`eval` evaluates this expression to get an integer.

PS: It is a very bad idea to use `eval` on unsanitized user input text. Imagine what will happen if the user enters some malicious code as input.

Answer (score 0):

`s.split()` creates a list of strings formed by the whitespace-separated parts of `s`.

`(... for token in s.split())` iterates through each of the strings in that list.

`token.lstrip('0')` removes leading zeros from each string.

`"".join` glues together all the zero-removed tokens, so `"".join(token.lstrip('0') for token in s.split())` is now a string that looks like an arithmetic expression.

`eval("".join(token.lstrip('0') for token in s.split()))` tells Python to treat the string as Python code, so it returns an `int` rather than a `str`. BTW, using `eval` is generally a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).

The final result is the original string, with whitespace removed, evaluated as a number.